# ui-router states that have different views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have several pages on my app, and each one of them has it's own view

those are the states:

login
posts
posts.post
cities
cities.post

I place "posts.post" and "cities.post" to be a son of posts and cities because I want to be able to click back and go to the referencer page.

"post" page is the same exactly in: posts.post, cities.post

but when I do this than the post inherits the view of cities or posts, and I don't want it, because it has it's own unique view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another method to name your states instead of dot notation?

There are several ways of nesting states:

-Use the ui-router.stateHelper to build states from a nested state tree. Courtesy of @marklagendijk.

-Using the parent property with the parent name as string. For example: parent: 'contacts'

-Using the parent property with the parent object. For example parent: contacts (where 'contacts' is a stateObject)